# Skewed normal distribution where y goes to 0 for fixed values of x (0 and 1 here)

Tags: skew-normal-distribution

I am trying to generate simulated data for gases. For any gas I want both the highest and lowest input values to produce the outcome 0 (or very near 0). And I want the 'peak input fraction' to produce the value 1, or very near. The other values should form a skewed bell curve.

For example with oxygen 11 is the lowest possible and 23 the highest possible, while the modal value is 21. Translated into a simple x,y graph, which goes from 0 to 1 on both x and y axes, the 'peak input fraction' would be the x value of (21-11)/(23-11) or 10/12.

I am looking for a formula for a function that can be 'seeded' with a fraction, and thereafter given any value of x between 0 and 1, will return a value for y between 0 and 1. The closer x is to the 'peak input fraction', the more likely the y result will be 1. And if I plot the results I should get a skewed bell-shaped curve where the peak of y is at the 'peak input fraction' of x.

Comment: There are any number of functions that satisfy your requirements. A scaled version of a beta density might work, but so might many other things. You may actually be better simply fitting some spline model that satisfies your conditions.